# python random choice on different rows

Tags: python, random

I've a problem, I would like randomly select two number on different rows of a matrix. And after, put those numbers on the same row but on the following columns for complete the matrix.

For example:

```
#I create a matrix "pop" where there are numbers in the first and second column and where there are zeros on the other columns
tab=np.array([[3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 6], [9, 8, 7, 8, 2, 0]]) 
tab1=tab.transpose()
pop=np.zeros((6,8),int)
pop[:,0:2]=tab1

#I create a function "next" which complete the matrix "pop" by a 
#random sampling with replacement  from the second previous column
def next (a):#a is the column of the data
    for i in range (0,6):#i is the row of the data
        pop[i,a]=np.random.choice(pop[:,(a-2)],1,replace=True)# select a number by a random choice from second previous column
        pop[i,a+1]=np.random.choice(pop[:,(a-1)],1,replace=True)


# loope to complete the data "pop"
for r in range(2,8):
    if r % 2 ==0:
        next(r)
```

But in my example, there exist a probability to choose two numbers on the same row of the matrix.

So I tried:

```
def whynot (a):#a is the column of the data
    for i in range (0,6):#i is the row of the data
        number=np.random.choice(pop[:,(a-1):(a-2)],2,replace=False)# select a number by a random choice from second previous column
        pop[i,a:a+1]=number
```

But it doesn't work... :_(

Thanks for your help!

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found something but it's long and I think there exist a better solution. But I post the script because maybe it can help someone.

```
def next (a):#a is the column of the data
    for i in range (0,6):#i is the row of the data
        number=np.arange(0,6,1)
        c=np.random.choice(number,1,replace=False)
        pop[i,a]=pop[c,a-2]# select a number by a random choice from second previous column
        toChooseFrom1 = np.concatenate((pop[:c,(a-2)], pop[(c+1):,(a-2)]))
        toChooseFrom2 = np.concatenate((pop[:c,(a-1)], pop[(c+1):,(a-1)]))
        tochoose=np.concatenate([toChooseFrom1,toChooseFrom2])
        np.random.shuffle(tochoose)
        pop[i,a+1]=np.random.choice(tochoose,1,replace=True)


# loope to complete the data "pop"
for r in range(2,8):
    if r % 2 ==0:
        next(r)
```